# How to make different animations on same page independantly start on hover and go to original state upon mouseleave with JQuery Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-transitions

Ok I search everywhere but I just cant find the answer to my question.

I have many CSS3 transitions and animations and actually want to implement them for internet explorer 8-9. However im pretty much a newcomer with javascript.

First this is my website http://tinyurl.com/axjuccx  you will see the css animations used.

Now, what im trying to achieve is the same but with Jquery animate() function.

As an example lets take this piece of code where I animate a div called block upon hovering over a button called go.

```
$("#go").mouseenter(function(){
  $("#block").animate({
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    marginLeft: "0.6in",
    fontSize: "3em",
    borderWidth: "10px"
  }, 1500 );
$("#go").mouseleave(function(){
  $("#block").animate({
    width: "70%",
    opacity: 0.4,
    marginLeft: "0.6in",
    fontSize: "3em",
    borderWidth: "10px"
  }, 1500 );
});
```

This does not seem to work and if I leave out the "mouseleave" part then it animates but stays at the animated state. I want it to revert back upon mouseleave.

Any help is appreciated.

Sincerely

Comment: so if you want to revert it why did you have the same .animate values for mouseenter and mouseleave? you could also use the mouseover function or the hover function if you experience problems..

Comment: My bad. I did have different values when I tested the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using stop() may help;

```
$("#go").hover(
  function () {
    $("#block").stop(true, true).animate(... your code here ...);
  }, 
  function () {
    $("#block").stop(true, true).animate(... your code here ...);
  }
);
```

JQuery stop(): http://api.jquery.com/stop/

JQuery hover(): http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: This seems to work just fine. I read the articles about stop but I didnt really understand how I could apply it until now. Thank you very much Turcia, it helped. Do you recommend that I place this code in an external js file? I assume that wouldnt work though. I have various transitions types sometimes so that might become a little heavy.

Comment: You need to test w and w/o external js then decide which one suits your needs.